# PK of the first Entity is not updating in second Entites referenced column --> hibernate spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

As the title says, I've 2 entity classes

Entity - 1

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity1", schema = "schema")
public class EntityOne {
   
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "first_id_seq")
   @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "[schema].[first_id_seq]", name = "first_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
   
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Integer id;
   
   private String name;
   
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityOne", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<EntityTwo> entityTwo;
}
```

Entity - 2

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity2", schema = "schema")
public class EntityTwo {
   
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "second_id_seq")
   @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "[schema].[second_id_seq]", name = "second_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Integer id;
   
   @Column(name = "vendor_id")
   private Integer vendorId;

   private String name;
   
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "vendor_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private EntityOne entityOne;
}
```

Finally when saving it i've DAO layer with method like this

```
@Repository
public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<EntityOne, Integer> {
}

public class DAO {
    
    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;

//consider this method getting called from controller
        public EnitityOne mapRequestToEntity(Request request) {
         EntityOne entityOne = new EntityOne();
         entityOne.setName(request.getName);
         List<EntityTwo> entityTwo = new ArrayList<>();
         // setting entityTwo values here from the request
         entityOne.setEntityTwo(entityTwo);
         entityOne = save(entityOne);
         return entityOne;
}
    
    public EntityOne save(EntityOne entityOne) {
        repository.saveAndFlush(entityOne);
    }
}
```

I'm saving the EntityOne from the controller, but when saving EnityOne's id(PK) should be mapped to EntityTwo's vendor_id and save but this is not happening. It is saving as `NULL`(null is accepted in db just for POC)

Comment: Could you provide examples of the code for the save procedure of both entities?

Comment: updated the question with more details

Comment: Still missing the part where you build the entities used by the Repository.

Comment: updated now, please check

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you are not associating EntityOne to EntityTwo has a field directly (using @OneToMany is not enough). Try saving EntityOne and then EntityTwo having it assigned its entityOne field. That should be enough.

Comment: As a work around I did as you suggested. But in an ideal scenario saving entity one should also save entity two right, once we establish the relation